# Recursively Query XML with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<tok id="9993" type="group">
  <tok id="144" type="atom" soff="686" eoff="693">
    <txt>popular</txt>
  </tok>
  <tok id="145" type="group">
     <tok id="144" type="atom" soff="686" eoff="693">
       <txt>movie</txt>
     </tok>
     <tok id="145" type="atom" soff="697" eoff="703">
       <txt>characters</txt>
     </tok>
  </tok>
</tok>
```

I have an XML document where I need to get the values of soff and eoff, but those values can be nested. I have tried using SelectMany(), but am doing something wrong. Above is an excerpt from the document. I basically want to get all of the "tok" where the type is "atom" so that I can get the two values I need from each like. My query is something like this:

```
 var queryHeadsTails2 = from h in xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("tok")
                        where (h.Attribute("id").Value == elem.entityID && h.Attribute("type").Value == "group")
                        select h;
```

Can I use SelectMany to get all of the rows where the type = "atom" or is there a better way?

The answer below

```
var groups = xmlDoc.Descendants("tok").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("type") == "group" && x.Elements("tok").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("type") == "atom").Any()).Select(x => new {
                        id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                        atoms = x.Elements("tok").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("type") == "atom").ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```

is very close, but it fails on this portion (trying to get the eoff and soff for group id 153527):

```
<tok id="153619" type="group">
    <tok id="80" type="atom" soff="388" eoff="390">
      <txt>in</txt>
    </tok>
    <tok id="153527" type="group">
      <tok id="153526" type="group">
        <tok id="81" type="atom" soff="391" eoff="396" no-space="true">
          <txt>today</txt>
        </tok>
        <tok id="82" type="atom" soff="396" eoff="398">
          <txt>'s</txt>
        </tok>
      </tok>
      <tok id="128206" type="group">
        <tok id="6360" type="group">
          <tok id="83" type="atom" soff="399" eoff="404">
            <txt>action</txt>
          </tok>
          <tok id="84" type="atom" soff="405" eoff="409">
            <txt>movie</txt>
          </tok>
        </tok>
        <tok id="85" type="atom" soff="410" eoff="418" no-space="true">
          <txt>industry</txt>
        </tok>
      </tok>
    </tok>
  </tok>
```

Is there a way to get just flatten it after I get the group I want? Kind of like where I started above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
           var groups = doc.Descendants("tok").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("type") == "group" && x.Elements("tok").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("type") == "atom").Any()).Select(x => new { id = (string)x.Attribute("id"), atoms = x.Elements("tok").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("type") == "atom").ToList() }).ToList();
```

Comment: Close, but fails in one instance. I altered my question to show where it fails. Thank you.

Comment: There is no atom in the child of 153527.  It work the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

In case VB'ers find this post...

First some test data

```
Dim xe As XElement
'to load
'  xe = XElement.Load("path / URI")
'for testing
xe = <tok id="9993" type="group">
         <tok id="144" type="atom" soff="687" eoff="693">
             <txt>popular</txt>
         </tok>
         <tok id="145" type="group">
             <tok id="144" type="atom" soff="686" eoff="693">
                 <txt>movie</txt>
             </tok>
             <tok id="145" type="atom" soff="697" eoff="703">
                 <txt>characters</txt>
             </tok>
         </tok>
     </tok>
```

Then the code to select  elements that have @type = "atom"

```
  Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xe...<tok>.Where(Function(el) el.@type = "atom")
```

And finally examine each of the selected elements

```
    For Each el As XElement In ie
        Debug.WriteLine("soff = {0}, eoff = {1}", el.@soff, el.@eoff)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help. It led me to this which seems to hit all cases:

```
var groups = from h in xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("tok")
             where (h.Attribute("id").Value == elem.entityID && h.Attribute("type").Value == "group")
             select new
             {
                  id = h.Attribute("id").Value,
                  atoms = h.Descendants("tok").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("type") == "atom").ToList()
              };
```